# Beginners Module error

Tags: xively

Hey guys just playing around with Xively at the moment with a PI.

I am having troubles getting my pi to run the python script tho.
https://xively.com/dev/tutorials/pi/#code
Was the tutorial i used but i keep getting this error.
    (venv)pi@raspberrypi /home/xively_tutorial $ python xively_tutorial.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xively_tutorial.py", line 4, in 
    import xively
ImportError: No module named xively

Any help on fixing this would be much appreciated.
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

My hunch is you have closed down the SSH session after the first install.  If you didn't re-source the "activate" command for the Python virtual environment, it wouldn't find the module.

Don't forget the "source .envs/.venv/bin/activate" command before running in a new SSH.